# How to list Views (or Widgets) in one scrollable screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following prototype:

[image]

What is the way to list views in a scroll-able way in a screen?

What I have already tried:

I tried to create a class and extends the LinearLayout class and dynamically adds my Views (the **compound controls class** is my ***view*** also extends LinearLayout) to the main LinearLayout. So I got a list of my views which is scroll-able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but looking at what you have tried, what's wrong with using a `ListView`? As the name implies, it should do exactly what you want:

> What is the way to list views in a scroll-able way in a screen?

Here is a quote from the [android documentation of a ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html%3a)

> ListView is a view group that displays a list of scrollable items. The
>   list items are automatically inserted to the list using an Adapter
>   that pulls content from a source such as an array or database query
>   and converts each item result into a view that's placed into the list.

You should be able to add a `ListView` directly as a sub-view under your `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

your questions seems like hard to understand.

did you mean how to set the whole page(activity) into a listview?
listviews are scrollable in default (of course, you can see it if the list is long enough and you can set the whole activity as a list).. you can customize it also by using templates (xml)
and extending `ArrayAdapter` of your type (let's say `ArrayAdapter<UpcomingEvents>`) and supply data from db...

is this what you mean?